# n_jobs = -1 equivalent in keras

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, keras, scikit-learn, cpu-usage

I have recently started learning deep learning. In machine learning using sklearn library with n_jobs = -1 all my cpu cores are used and this speeds the grid search. Now I am trying to fit an rnn model on training data, which is taking a lot of time . Is there a way I can speed up the training.

```
# Initialising the RNN
regressor = Sequential()

# Adding the first LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 7)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding a second LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding a third LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding a fourth LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding the output layer
regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))

# Compiling the RNN
regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

# Fitting the RNN to the Training set
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 100, batch_size = 32,shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count{"CPU": <NB CPU>})
keras.backend.tensorflow_backend.set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```